# Code Generation tool testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have written small `code generation` tool in `C++` , it is using `ANTLR C++` and input to the tool is `C++ header file`. Basically given a type , it call my product specific api
for example.

```
class Test {
private:
   int a;
   char b;
   long c;
public:
   serialize();
}
```

For this class it will generate code like below

```
Test::serialize() {
     serialize_int(a);
     serialize_char(b);
     serialize_long(c);
}
```

Now I can put this entire generated code in my existing `Unit Test` and verify the everything is working fine.

But is there any way to test this automatically using c++ only . I mean Given a type say `int` my tools has generated a call `serialize_int`

Comment: Would it be possible to expand on exactly what you're trying to accomplish? You're question is not entirely clear.

Comment: I want to test programatically that Given a class, my code generator is generating expected output.

Comment: I'm working on a code generator that is similar.  Rather than supporting int, which can be of different sizes, I support int8_t, int16_t and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you may try using [CATCH](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/wiki) or any other testing framework (boost, googletest, look for others). Certainly you have to write the test cases.